How to Use PyAirbyte to Connect Custom Data Sources (e.g., Redshift)
I'm looking for guidance on using PyAirbyte
https://docs.airbyte.com/using-airbyte/pyairbyte/getting-started
as an integration tool to easily connect multiple data sources, such as Redshift.
I reviewed the demo, but I want to replace the source-faker example with a custom source configuration that includes parameters like:

endpoint
username
password
database
table

Here’s the demo code for context:
```python
import airbyte as ab

source = ab.get_source(
    "source-faker",
    config={"count": 5_000},
    install_if_missing=True,
)
source.check()
source.select_all_streams()
result = source.read()

for name, records in result.streams.items():
    print(f"Stream {name}: {len(list(records))} records")
```

How can I modify this to use my own source with the specified parameters? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
